# Can I lower soundcard quality?

Tags: sound, music, soundcard, mp3

This is from an artistic standpoint, not means of technological improvement.

Is it possible to lower the sound quality that leaves my soundcard?
To be more exact, can I make everything that leaves my computer sound like an 8kpbs mp3 through some terminal-magic in ubuntu, and hopefully with a cheap way back?

Thanks.

Comment: This, sir or madam, is an awesome question!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is some terminal-magic that will work.
A small configuration script to change your sounddriver a bit is all that you need.

When you remove the script everything will be back to normal.

For documentation: Follow [this](http://www.alsa-project.org/main/index.php/Asoundrc) link and what you want to do is mentioned under "Plugins".

Comment: The link seems to be missing.

Comment: Sorry for that...it's fixed now